# Flutter App Incompatibility Issue: "This item is not available" on Google Play Store

Tags: android, flutter, sdk, google-play, android-manifest

I recently encountered an issue while uploading a Flutter app bundle to the Google Play Store for internal testing. Some devices are showing an error message stating, "This item is not available" and the details mention that the app is incompatible with the device.

The app uses the feature `android.hardware.faketouch` and has only the `internet` permission.
The `minSdk` version is set to 21, `targetSdk` version is set to 33, and `compileSdk` version is set to 33.

I found that the app works correctly on devices such as Poco F3 (Android 13).
However, on a Realme 8 5G (Android 12), the app fails to work, and the Google Play Store shows the aforementioned error message.

I have researched similar questions on this platform and found that some users were able to resolve their compatibility issues by fixing the SDK versions. However, in my case, the app's SDK versions seem to be appropriately configured.

Here is a snippet of my AndroidManifest.xml file for reference:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="it.manudicri.chordship">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <application android:label="Chordship" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:exported="true">
      <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
      <meta-data android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme" android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />
      <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
      <meta-data android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable" android:resource="@drawable/launch_background" />
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
    <meta-data android:name="flutterEmbedding" android:value="2" />
  </application>
</manifest>
```

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this problem.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Best regards,
Manuel